# How to get network name and chain Id to which metamask wallet is connected using Ether.js library?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js

I am looking for a solution that I would use in my Dapp to get the network name and the chain Id of the network to which the wallet is connected using [**Ether.js**](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/) library

For example, if my wallet is connected to the Goerli network, I should get the network name as *'goerli'* and the chain id as *5*. What would be the code for that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use ether.js, but I try to help with my solution: I use wagmi library with react.
wagmi library is simple.

```
import { useNetwork } from 'wagmi'

function App() {
   const { chain, chains } = useNetwork()

   return (
      <>
         {chain && <div>Connected to {chain.name}</div>}
         {chains && (
            <div>Available chains: {chains.map((chain) => chain.name)} 
            </div>
         )}
      </>
   )
}
```

wagmi docs: https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useNetwork

Comment: I appreciate your help but I need the code for ether.js library only.

Comment: heyy Did you find something about this???????

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import abi from '../abi.json';

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);

try{
    const tx = await contract.customContractFunction(value1, value2);
    return tx;
}catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

try this code

Comment: This is an answer not related to OP question

Answer (score 1):

After creating a new ethers provider ( passing in window.ethereum ),
to get chainId and name, use the getNetwork() method on your provider which will return an object with fields such as name,chainId,etc.
There you have it

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the Metamask and other Ethereum-based wallets inject an object called **ethereum** into the **window** object. The **ethereum** object offers a variety of properties and methods that we could use. Let's assume that you have the Metamask wallet installed; open your browser's console, and run `> window.ethereum`. You should get output similar to this: [image: window.ethereum]

As we can see, the **ethereum** object offers **chainId**, and **networkVersion** properties that we can tap into (see example below). However, both of the options are depreciated at this point and are considered to be legacy APIs. I'd like you to, please read more in [Ethereum Provider API - Legacy Properties](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#legacy-api). The recommended way is to use the **request()** method, which takes an object describing your request and returns a Promise. The promise gets eventually resolved with the requested data. To query chain id, we send the following object to our request() function **window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_chainId'})** and we receive `0x5`, which is network id for **Goerli** network:
[image: window.ethereum.request()]

The method described above does not offer the network name, so you could create a custom object that maps the network chain id to the network name.

The other method you could use is to employ **ethers.providers.getNetwork()** function from [Ethers Library](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/#providers--networks), which return an object containing **chainId** and network **name** properties:

```js
// By Chain ID
getNetwork(5);
// {
//   chainId: 5,
//   ensAddress: '0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e',
//   name: 'goerli'
// }
```

Implementing these concepts might differ and depends mainly on your framework and libraries. However, it could look something like that within Next.js 13 page component:

```js
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Getting nework name and id...");
    async function getChainId() {
      try {
        const chainId = Number(await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_chainId" }));
        const network = ethers.providers.getNetwork(chainId);
        console.log(`Network name: ${network.name}, id:${network.chainId}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getChainId();
  }, []);
  return <></>;
}
```

[image]